# Python: best/efficient way of finding a list of words in a text?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of approximately 300 words and a huge amount of text that I want to scan to know how many times each word appears.

I am using the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module from python:

```
for word in list_word:
    search = re.compile(r"""(\s|,)(%s).?(\s|,|\.|\))""" % word)
    occurrences = search.subn("", text)[1]
```

but I want to know if there is a more efficient or more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: you could use a wordbound instead of checking for surrounding spaces and punctuation. `\bWORD\b`

Comment: If you want to go beyond word frequency and look into text classification, you may want to look at this:
http://streamhacker.com/2010/06/16/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-eliminate-low-information-features/

Comment: How **huge** can the text be if you are holding it in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a huge amount of text, I wouldn't use regexps in this case but simply split text:

```
words = {"this": 0, "that": 0}
for w in text.split():
  if w in words:
    words[w] += 1
```

words will give you the frequency for each word

Comment: Definitely more efficient to only scan the text once. Code snippet above just seems to be missing the check that the word is one of the 300 "important" ones.

Comment: @pdbartlett `if w in words` makes that check.

Comment: Splitting on whitespace isn't always going to lead to perfect results. If you need sophisticated splitting, you can take a look at NLTK, which has been suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Try stripping all the punctuation from your text and then splitting on whitespace. Then simply do

```
for word in list_word:
    occurence = strippedText.count(word)
```

Or if you're using python 3.0 I think you could do:

```
occurences = {word: strippedText.count(word) for word in list_word}
```

Comment: in 2.6 <= python < 3.0 you can do `occurences = dict((word, strippedText.count(word)) for word in list_word)`

Answer (score 0):

Googling: python frequency
gives me this page as the first result: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216747.html

Which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Its un-pythonish with all these regexes. Splitting into separate words is best achieved with str.split() rather than custom regex

Comment: you're right, if the Python string functions are sufficient, they should be used in lieu of regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also split the text into words and search the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions may not be what you want. Python has a number of built-in string operations that are **much** faster, and I believe .count() has what you need.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Answer (score 0):

If Python is not a must, you can use awk

```
$ cat file
word1
word2
word3
word4

$ cat file1
blah1 blah2 word1 word4 blah3 word2
junk1 junk2 word2 word1 junk3
blah4 blah5 word3 word6 end

$ awk 'FNR==NR{w[$1];next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}END{for(i in w){ if(i in a) print i,a[i] } } ' file file1
word1 2
word2 2
word3 1
word4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the Natural Language Toolkit might have what you need.

http://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Specifically the `nltk.FreqDist` class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could adapt this my multisearch generator function.

```
    from itertools import islice
testline = "Sentence 1.  Sentence 2?  Sentence 3!  Sentence 4.  Sentence 5."
def multis(search_sequence,text,start=0):
    """ multisearch by given search sequence values from text, starting from position start
        yielding tuples of text before sequence item and found sequence item"""
    x=''
    for ch in text[start:]:
        if ch in search_sequence:
            if x: yield (x,ch)
            else: yield ch
            x=''
        else:
            x+=ch
    else:
        if x: yield x

# split the first two sentences by the dot/question/exclamation.
two_sentences = list(islice(multis('.?!',testline),2)) ## must save the result of generation
print "result of split: ", two_sentences

print '\n'.join(sentence.strip()+sep for sentence,sep in two_sentences)
```